# Why "webp" format of picture doesn''t work

Tags: html, css, webp

I would like to use new "webp" format instead of old ones, however, there is a problem.

When usual format is used, it's correct.

```
<div id="logo">
            <img src="~/css/background.png" alt="">
</div>

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}

#logo img { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
```

When I use "webp", the picture isn't shown.

```
<div id="logo">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="~/css/background.webp" type="image/webp">
            <source srcset="~/css/background.png" type="image/jpeg">
        </picture>
    </div>

#logo {
   <same styles>
}

#logo source { 
    <same styles>
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you certain the image itself is saved as `webp` format?  Not just renamed `.webp` ?

Comment: @Zak, yes, I converted it

Comment: Does your server set the correct MIME type on the .webp files?